# Feed a command-line shell from another shell

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, usability

This question may sound weird but I'll explain the context and hopefully it will justify it. I'm on Linux trying to work with some ill-made shells.

I have to work with `fdb` and `fcsh`, which are Adobe's commandline debugger and compiler shells for Flash. This isn't particularly relevant - only the fact that *they're shells*, i.e. you run `fdb`, it gives you a prompt like `(fdb)` and you type commands. All cool.

BUT. Say you want to re-execute your last command, so you hit [Arrow-Up] on your keyboard, like you'd do in Bash, Python Shell, GDB shell etc. And it doesn't work. Instead of seeing the last command at the prompt, I see `(fdb) ^[[A` (note that `(fdb)` is the prompt). Pressing the [Arrow-Left] key to go back a few characters and fix your typed command - same story.

This looks like Adobe didn't make its shells very well. Is there a way to open a simple bash shell (or something) that will keep feeding my commands to an open `fdb` shell, kept as a daemon? I hope that this way I get Bash's neat usability features for handling commands, but get them executed by `fdb`.

*Note:* I have found [this wrapper](https://github.com/Draknek/fcsh-wrap/blob/master/fcsh-wrap) which keeps `fcsh` daemonized and holds it's pid file, I think. This is cool. I haven't used it yet, but considering it. Still, my question holds: is there a way to pipe commands from one shell to another?

Comment: The comment "Adobe didn't make its shells very well" is not well substantiated.  I have never used either of these shells and know nothing about them, so perhaps they are lousy, but certainly not based on a lack of builtin support for command history.  I would argue that a shell that does its own history support is lousy, since it is a feature better left to things like rlwrap.  Modularity is good.  Integration is bad.

Comment: Please note that I'm almost nit-picking. I'm glad I have these shells. On top of that, `fdb` is almost like GDB, if you look at the commands. A big plus. Still, a shell is quite lacking when it doesn't have such history support. GDB has it, Python has it, GHCi has it etc, and I don't run them in `rlwrap`. I have no idea whether they bind against the `rlwrap` library, or if they run it for me, or if they implemented it themselves (integrated vs modularity?). But they have it, it's important (to me?), and `fdb` and `fcsh` don't have it. The shells are good, but lacking this. Hence my complaint.

Comment: And I didn't say "lousy". No way :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash uses GNU readline library which can be used only for open source programs (with an appropriate license). But you can use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/rlwrap.html). It is in most Linux distributives. You can use it as `rlwrap fdb`, for example.

Comment: This looks awesome. Will check soon.